How to simulate a scenario 1,000 times with sample size varying from 100-200 in R?
I need to simulate specific scenarios 1,000 times (to get the mean of an estimated value). Additionally, various sample sizes need to be specified.
My R Code so far includes (an simpler) scenario which is repeated 1,000 for the sample size n=100. Now I need to run the code for sample size 101, 102, 103, ...
I'm quite sure that a for-loop is needed, but I do not know how to write down.
As a result I want a data frame, containing a column with the sample size and a column with the mean of the 1,000 runs.
I would be very thankful, if anyone could help :)
My R Code:
    simulation <- function(n){
      
      id <-  1:n
      trt <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.2)
      x  <- rnorm(n, 0 , 1)
      data <- data.frame(id, trt, x)
      
      Mean.1 <- aggregate(data[, 3], list(data$trt), mean)[1,2]
      Mean.2 <- aggregate(data[, 3], list(data$trt), mean)[2,2]
      s.1 <- aggregate(data[, 3], list(data$trt), sd)[1,2]
      s.2 <- aggregate(data[, 3], list(data$trt), sd)[2,2]
      n.1 <- table(data$trt)[1]
      n.2 <-  table(data$trt)[2]
      
      
      #SMD
      d_con <- (Mean.1 - Mean.2)/(sqrt((s.1^2+s.2^2)/2))
      
      
      # z-difference
      z_con <- (Mean.1 - Mean.2)/(sqrt(s.1^2/n.1+s.2^2/n.2))
      tibble(d_con, z_con)
    }
    
    # Run simulation
    results <- tibble()
    
    for(i in 1:1000){
      results <- bind_rows(results, simulation(100))}
    
    
# a data frame containing means of d_con and z_con per sample size
# I only have sample size n=100

    sample_size <- c(100)
    mean_d <- mean(results$d_con)
    mean_z <- mean(results$z_con)
    
    final <- data.frame(sample_size, mean_d, mean_z)


As an aside, for(i in 1:1000){results <- bind_rows(results, simulation(100))} is highly inefficient.  See, fopr example, Chapter 3 of The R Inferno.  One way to avoid this is to convert your code to use a member of the *apply family and then bind the results together.

To answer your question, simply nest your current loop (whether as is or using lapply) within another loop for the sample size - remembering to  replace simulation(100) with, say, simulation(sampleSize).

First, I'll adapt your function to make it work with lapply - and to add a piece of information to your results data frame.
The change is simple:
# Note the addition of a new parameter
simulation <- function(i, n){

Note the new, first, argument i, which will be a loop index.  It's important that it's the first parameter.
And the final line of the function changes to:
  tibble(d_con, z_con, sim = i)

Now your loop becomes:
# Run simulation: reduced to 200 simply for speed
nSims <- 200
lapply(
  100:105,
  function(n) {
    lapply(1:nSims, simulation, n = n) %>% 
      bind_rows() %>% 
      add_column(n = n)
  }
) %>% bind_rows()

    lapply(1:nSims, simulation, n = n) %>% 
      bind_rows() %>% 
      add_column(n = n)

Is your current loop, rewritten using lapply.  The outer loop iterates over sample size.
Output is
# A tibble: 1,200 × 4
      d_con   z_con   sim     n
      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 -0.458   -1.80       1   100
 2 -0.274   -1.10       2   100
 3  0.213    0.956      3   100
 4 -0.469   -1.81       4   100
 5  0.148    0.562      5   100
 6  0.467    1.76       6   100
 7 -0.334   -1.47       7   100
 8  0.123    0.477      8   100
 9  0.00413  0.0175     9   100
10  0.153    0.601     10   100
# ℹ 1,190 more rows

This solution uses the tidyverse, but I think you're implicitly doing so already.  If not, you'll need to add
library(tidyverse)

before running your code.

Thank you it is working fine! Is it possible to aggregate the n's within the lapply()-function? I'm doing something like "nSims <- 200
results <- lapply(
100:105,
function(n) {
lapply(1:nSims, simulation, n = n) %>%
bind_rows() %>%
add_column(n = n)
}
) %>% bind_rows()" and "final <- aggregate(results[, c(1,2)], list(results$n), mean)" afterwards.. Is it possible to not present each run, but rather the mean of the 200 runs?

Yes.  Just modify the body of the inner lapply.  Something like lapply(1:nSims, simulation, n = n) %>% bind_rows() %>% summarise(across(ends_with("con"), mean)).

So one easy to iterate through a simulation is simply create a simulation table which the inputs you want to vary the simulation by then using rowwise to pass your function through each row of the table running it with all the parameters.
This will return a nested table that you can simply unnest when you are ready.
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  n=100:105
) |> 
  crossing(
    sim=1:10
  ) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    fun=list(simulation(n))
  ) |> 
  unnest(fun)


